# Keyboard input arduino speed

Tags: arduino-leonardo, time, keyboard

I have an Arduino clone of a Leonardo and I was just wondering how many keyboard commands I can send to the computer per second via USB. I'm not talking about the delay between send and receive (because that could vary between computer), I'm talking about the minimum possible time between something like stimulating a key press down and key press up as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

From my tests, it has been at least 1 millisecond, however, it can depend on what is running simultaneously on the Arduino.

Comment: Well what if you were doing key up and key down of a single character, with that only being in the void loop?